# Will a spacecraft with angular momentum have to course correct if it thrusts along the same axis as its rotation?

Tags: angular-momentum, rocket-science

For the sake of illustration, let's say you have a cylindrical spacecraft, sitting "at rest" in space, relatively speaking. It has a thruster on one end. If it fires the thruster, it goes forward in a straight line, in the direction opposite the thruster.

[image]

But what happens if that same cylindrical spacecraft is spinning before you fire the thruster? I have learned from [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPUuF_dECVI) that if you apply torque to an object with angular momentum, the object will tilt, as the spin angular momentum moves in the direction of the torque. But I'm not clear on if this thruster would be applying torque or not. Would this spacecraft have the same trajectory in both cases, or would the spinning case result in it going some other direction?

Comment: I like your diagrams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was torque, the vehicle that started out at rest would start spinning because of it, so neither case would result in straight line motion.  In theory, you would only have torque if the thruster was misaligned with the vehicle's center of mass, which isn't the case in your diagram.

In practice, rotating around the axis of motion helps to stabilize an object against rotations in other directions, so if anything the rotation would actually help to keep it moving straight.  Spacecraft are sometimes "spin-stabilized" by intentionally making them rotate like this.  This is also the reason for the "rifling" in the barrels of firearms.